# Select rows matching the pattern: greater_than, less_than, greater_than

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Got a database with entries indicating units earned by staff. Am trying to find a query that can select for me entries where the `units_earned` by the staff follow this pattern: `>30` then `<30` and then `>30`

In [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e5613/1), I would expect the query to return:

For John, Rows:

> 2, 4, 6
>
> 9, 10, 11

For Jane, Rows:

> 3, 5, 8
>
> 12, 13, 14

**Here is the relevant SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE staff_units(
   id integer,
   staff_number integer,
   first_name varchar(50),
   month_name varchar(3),
   units_earned integer,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (1, 101, 'john', 'jan', 32);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (2, 101, 'john', 'jan', 33);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (3, 102, 'jane', 'jan', 39);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (4, 101, 'john', 'feb', 28);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (5, 102, 'jane', 'feb', 28);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (6, 101, 'john', 'mar', 39);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (7, 101, 'john', 'mar', 34);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (8, 102, 'jane', 'mar', 40);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (9, 101, 'john', 'mar', 36);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (10, 101, 'john', 'apr', 18);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (11, 101, 'john', 'may', 32);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (12, 102, 'jane', 'jun', 31);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (13, 102, 'jane', 'jun', 28);
INSERT INTO staff_units VALUES (14, 102, 'jane', 'jun', 32);
```

Comment: Edit your question and put the sample data *in the question*.  The SQL Fiddle link doesn't work.

Comment: added.. though in my side the fiddle is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) `lead` you can refer to the next two leading records of the current record and then compare the three against your desired pattern.

```
with staff_units_with_leading as (
select id, staff_number, first_name, units_earned, 
  lead(units_earned) over w units_earned_off1,    -- units_earned from record with offset 1
  lead(units_earned, 2) over w units_earned_off2, -- units_earned from record with offset 2
  lead(id) over w id_off1,    -- id from record with offset 1
  lead(id, 2) over w id_off2  -- id from record with offset 2
from staff_units
window w as (partition by first_name order by id)
)
, ids_wanted as (
select  unnest(array[id, id_off1, id_off2]) id  -- 
from staff_units_with_leading
where 
  id_off1 is not null      -- Discard records with no two leading records
  and id_off2 is not null  -- Discard records with no two leading records
  and units_earned > 30       -- Match desired pattern
  and units_earned_off1 < 30  -- Match desired pattern
  and units_earned_off2 > 30  -- Match desired pattern
)
select * from staff_units
where id in (select id from ids_wanted)
  order by  staff_number, id;
```

To generate trigrams just get rid of the unnest

```
with staff_units_with_leading as (
select id, staff_number, first_name, units_earned, 
  lead(units_earned) over w units_earned_off1,    -- units_earned from record with offset 1
  lead(units_earned, 2) over w units_earned_off2, -- units_earned from record with offset 2
  lead(id) over w id_off1,    -- id from record with offset 1
  lead(id, 2) over w id_off2  -- id from record with offset 2
from staff_units
window w as (partition by first_name order by id)
)
select  staff_number, array[id, id_off1, id_off2] id, array[units_earned , units_earned_off1 , units_earned_off2 ] units_earned  -- 
from staff_units_with_leading
where 
  id_off1 is not null      -- Discard records with no two leading records
  and id_off2 is not null  -- Discard records with no two leading records
  and units_earned > 30       -- Match desired pattern
  and units_earned_off1 < 30  -- Match desired pattern
  and units_earned_off2 > 30  -- Match desired pattern
```

Comment: Oh, completely forgot about lead(). Nice :-)

Comment: Updated to generate trigrams.

Answer (score 1):

I took cachique's answer (with excellent idea to use lead() ) and reformatted and extended it to generate 3-grams as you originally wanted:

```
with staff_units_with_leading as (
  select
    id, staff_number, first_name, units_earned, 
    lead(units_earned) over w units_earned_off1,    -- units_earned from record with offset 1
    lead(units_earned, 2) over w units_earned_off2, -- units_earned from record with offset 2
    lead(id) over w id_off1,    -- id from record with offset 1
    lead(id, 2) over w id_off2  -- id from record with offset 2
  from staff_units
  window w as (partition by staff_number order by id)
), ids_wanted as (
  select
    id_off1,                 -- keep this to group 3-grams later
    unnest(array[id, id_off1, id_off2]) id
  from staff_units_with_leading
  where 
    id_off1 is not null      -- Discard records with no two leading records
    and id_off2 is not null  -- Discard records with no two leading records
    and units_earned > 30       -- Match desired pattern
    and units_earned_off1 < 30  -- Match desired pattern
    and units_earned_off2 > 30  -- Match desired pattern
), res as (
  select su.*, iw.id_off1
  from staff_units su
  join ids_wanted iw on su.id = iw.id
  order by su.staff_number, su.id
)
select
  staff_number,
  array_agg(units_earned order by id) as values,
  array_agg(id order by id) as ids
from res
group by staff_number, id_off1
order by 1
;
```

The result will be:

```
 staff_number |   values    |    ids
--------------+------------+------------
          101 | {33,28,39} | {2,4,6}
          101 | {36,18,32} | {9,10,11}
          102 | {39,28,40} | {3,5,8}
          102 | {31,28,32} | {12,13,14}
(4 rows)
```

Comment: This has got the better presentation. Let me run it against my main DB to see how the results will be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're trying to solve is a bit complicated. It is probably easier to solve it if you'll use pl/pgsql and play with integer arrays inside pl/pgsql function, or probably with JSON/JSONB.

But it also can be solved in plain SQL, however such SQL is pretty advanced.

```
with rows_numbered as (
  select
    *, row_number() over (partition by staff_number order by id) as row_num
  from staff_units
  order by staff_number
), sequences (staff_number, seq) as (
  select
    staff_number,
    json_agg(json_build_object('row_num', row_num, 'id', id, 'units_earned', units_earned) order by id)
  from rows_numbered
  group by 1
)
select
  s1.staff_number,
  (s1.chunk->>'id')::int as id1,
  (s2.chunk->>'id')::int as id2,
  (s3.chunk->>'id')::int as id3
from (select staff_number, json_array_elements(seq) as chunk from sequences) as s1
, lateral (
  select *
  from (select staff_number, json_array_elements(seq) as chunk from sequences) _
  where
    (s1.chunk->>'row_num')::int + 1 = (_.chunk->>'row_num')::int
    and (_.chunk->>'units_earned')::int < 30
    and s1.staff_number = _.staff_number
) as s2
, lateral (
  select *
  from (select staff_number, json_array_elements(seq) as chunk from sequences) _
  where
    (s2.chunk->>'row_num')::int + 1 = (_.chunk->>'row_num')::int
    and (_.chunk->>'units_earned')::int > 30
    and s2.staff_number = _.staff_number
) as s3
where (s1.chunk->>'units_earned')::int > 30
order by 1, 2;
```

I used several advanced SQL features:

- CTE
- JSON
- LATERAL
- window functions.